# SVM in R e1071 package yields different outputs for different formula notation but same data and parameters

Tags: r, svm, predict, confusion-matrix

For the purpose of doing Twitter sentiment analysis I am using the SVM function from e1071 package.
I used the RTextTools package to create a document term matrix which I split into a training and a test set. I have "train" which is a data frame of training observations excluding the predicted variable. Then I have "sentitrain", which is a vector of sentiment values corresponding to the training set. Same for testing. 
Then I used three different ways for fitting the a SVM model.
Firstly, I created a container

```
trainmat = as.matrix(train)
# create container object
traincontainer = create_container(trainmat, 
                           sentitrain,
                           trainSize = 1:nrow(trainmat), 
                           virgin = FALSE)

# create test matrix


testmat = as.matrix(test)
testcontainer = create_container(testmat, labels = rep(0, nrow(test)), 
                               testSize = 1:nrow(test), virgin = FALSE)

model <- train_model(traincontainer , "SVM", kernel="radial", cost=400)
results = classify_model(testcontainer, model)
preds = results[,1]
confusionMatrix(table(preds, sentitest))
```

This gave me approximately 76% classification accuracy.

In the second method I simply took the column names of my training matrix and then created a formula:

```
n = names(train)
# exclude the predicted variable
n = setdiff(n, c("sentiment"))
predictors = paste(n, collapse = " + ")

# create formula
f = as.formula(paste("sentiment ~ ", predictors))

model = svm(f, data = train, cost = 400, kernel = "radial")    
preds = predict(model, test)
confusionMatrix(table(preds, sentitest))
```

This gave me around 69% accuracy.

Thirdly I just passed the data frames and the vectors of predicted values directly to the function call:

```
model = svm(train, sentitrain, data = train, cost = 400, kernel = 
"radial")    
preds = predict(model, test)
confusionMatrix(table(preds, sentitest))
```

This resulted in an astonishing 87% accuracy.
I ran each model several times with cross validation to make sure these differences were not due to randomness.
As I understand it I always used the same function from the same package (RTextTools calls the SVM function from e1071 internally) with the same parameters on the same data. The only difference is the way I passed those parameters. How can the results be so different?